# What is difference between two delegate methods for didReceiveRemoteNotification in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification

I have implemented `Push Notification` in my iOS app.I can see two `delegate` methods for `didReceiveRemoteNotification` like the below methods: What is the difference between these two methods?

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo { }
```

and

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
    fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler {
  completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData);
}
```

Comment: check this link you got idea http://cleanswifter.com/ios-10-local-notifications/

Answer (score 3):

The first one is deprecated in iOS 10.0 use the second one. Information for second one

> This method will be invoked even if the application was launched or resumed because of the remote notification. The respective delegate methods will be invoked first. Note that this behavior is in contrast to application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:, which is not called in those cases, and which will not be invoked if this method is implemented.

And for first one

> Use UserNotifications Framework's -[UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate willPresentNotification:withCompletionHandler:] or -[UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate didReceiveNotificationResponse:withCompletionHandler:] for user visible notifications and -[UIApplicationDelegate application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:fetchCompletionHandler:] for silent remote notifications

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo { }**
```

Called when your app has received a remote notification. This method is **deprecated** in iOS 10.0

For more details click [here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623117-application?language=objc)

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo     fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler {   completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData); }**
```

Tells the app that a remote notification arrived that indicates there is data to be fetched.

For more details click [here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623013-application?language=objc)

Answer (score 0):

The below method is updated one

This delegate method offers an opportunity for applications with the "remote-notification" background mode to fetch appropriate new data in response to an incoming remote notification. You should call the fetchCompletionHandler as soon as you're finished performing that operation, so the system can accurately estimate its power and data cost.

This method will be invoked even if the application was launched or resumed because of the remote notification. The respective delegate methods will be invoked first. Note that this behavior is in contrast to application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:, which is not called in those cases, and which will not be invoked if this method is implemented.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo     fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler
 {
   completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You app needs to handle all the possible push notification delivery states:

Your app was just launched

Your app was just brought from background to foreground

Your app was already running in the foreground

1. You can tell whether your app was just brought to the foreground or not in didReceiveRemoteNotification using this bit of code:  **Deprecated in iOS 10.0**

   - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application 
     didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo;
2. Tells the app that a remote notification arrived that indicates there is data to be fetched. Use this method to process incoming remote notifications for your app. Unlike the `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:` method, which is called only when your app is running in the foreground, the system calls this method when your app is running in the foreground or background. In addition, if you enabled the remote notifications background mode, the system launches your app (or wakes it from the suspended state) and puts it in the background state when a remote notification arrives. However, the system does not automatically launch your app if the user has force-quit it. In that situation, the user must relaunch your app or restart the device before the system attempts to launch your app automatically again.

   - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application 
     didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo 
     fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult result))completionHandler;

In addition

> The block to execute when the download operation is complete. When calling this block, pass in the fetch result value that best describes the results of your download operation. You must call this handler and should do so as soon as possible. For a list of possible values, see the UIBackgroundFetchResult type.